# Simplify $\sum (x_i- \mu)^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

How can I simplify this relation?
$$\sum_{i = 1}^m(X_i-\mu)^2=\sum_{i = 1}^m(X_i-\bar{X}_m)^2+m(\bar{X}_m-\mu)^2$$
I know how to set up:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^m(X_i-\mu)^2=\sum_{i = 1}^m[(X_i-\bar{X}_m)+(\bar{X}_m-\mu)]^2$$
but when I open the bracket, how do I handle the mixed term?
$$2\sum_{i = 1}^m(X_i-\bar{X}_m)(\bar{X}_m-\mu)$$

Thank you!

Comment: You can pull out $(\overline{X}-\mu)$ and put it in front. Then what is inside the sum will be $m\overline{X} - m\overline{X} =0$. Get it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution that might add extra intuition.
Let $Y$ be a random draw from $X_{1},\ldots,X_{m}$. Note that $E[Y]=\bar{X}$ and $Var[Y]=E[(Y-\bar{X})^2]=m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$. Also, for
every random variable $Y$, $E[(Y-\mu)^2]=(E[Y]-\mu)^2+Var[Y]$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
 E[(Y-\mu)^2] 
 &= (E[Y]-\mu)^2 + Var[Y] \\
 m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(X_i-\mu)^2}
 &= (\bar{X}-\mu)^2 + m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2} \\
 \sum_{i=1}^{m}{(X_i-\mu)^2}
 &= (\bar{X}-\mu)^2 + m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}
\end{align*}

In other words, this result is essentially the same as the one that says that the mean squared error of a random variable is the square of its bias plus its variance.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\sum_{i = 1}^m(X_i-\bar{X}_m)(\bar{X}_m-\mu)=2(\bar{X}_m-\mu)\sum_{i = 1}^m (X_i-\bar{X}_m)$$

but we have

$$\sum_{i = 1}^m(X_i-\bar{X}_m)= \sum_{i = 1}^m X_i-\sum_{i = 1}^m \bar{X}_m =\sum_{i = 1}^m X_i - m\bar{X}_m=0$$

since $$\bar{X}_m = \frac1m\sum_{i = 1}^m X_i.$$